# Get-WMIObject Output and Error Handling

Tags: error-handling, wmi, powershell-2.0

Trying to get some output from a PowerShell scan for some software which should exists on all workstations.

```bsh
Get-Content -Path f:\desktop\Machines.csv |
    ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $_} |
    Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -like "*Adobe Reader*"} |
    Select-Object -Property PSComputerName,Name,Version |
    Export-Csv -Path f:\desktop\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is I don't get any information in the output file with those machines that do not have the software installed.  I often get RPC Server unavailable errors in the ISE console but that information doesn't make it to the output file.

I guess I'm actually looking for output reporting machines that do or do not have the software as well as any error message while attempting to reach the machines to check.

Answer (score 1):

Move filter and selection inside the `ForEach-Object` and create a custom object if the result turns up empty.

```bsh
Get-Content 'F:\desktop\Machines.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $o = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $_ |
         Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Adobe Reader*"} |
         Select-Object PSComputerName,Name,Version
    if ($o) {
        $o
    } else {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'PSComputerName' = $_
            'Name'           = 'Adobe Reader'
            'Version'        = $null
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv 'F:\desktop\Results.csv' -NoType
```

Note, however, that `Win32_Product` is [considered harmful](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/). It's recommended to use registry queries instead.